# Sending hex values over telnet in python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I'm trying to send a series of single hex bytes over telnet, but I'm facing some problems.

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet('192.168.4.1', 23, 5)

a = [0xFF, 0x0C]
b = a[1]
b = chr(b)
b = bytes(b, 'ascii')

tn.write(b)

raise SystemExit
```

I can't send the entire range from 0x00 to 0xFF. When I try to send 0xFF for example, it says

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xff' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

And I must absolutely send a whole hex byte at a time, to be received by an STM32 UART module.

If I only write

```
a = [0xFF, 0x0C]
b = a[1]    
tn.write(chr(b))
```

It gives me

> TypeError: 'in < string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes

How can I send Hex bytes over telnet using variables?

Comment: Use `'latin-1'` instead of `'ascii'`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!